# Overloading in Scala when type parameters are being used

Tags: scala, types, overloading

Look at this piece of code I am working on at the moment (It's meant to parse some arguments from the arguments of the main method):

```
def parser[T](identifier: String, default: T, modifier: String => T): T = {
  val l = args.filter(_.startsWith(identifier))
  if(l.isEmpty) default
  else modifier(l(0).drop(identifier.length).trim)
}
```

I also intended to write an overloaded method that deals with the case of Strings:

```
def parser(identifier: String, default: String): String = parser[String](identifier, default, identity)
```

The compiler does not seem to be impressed with this and will not allow me to overload the method. I have to change the name of either of the methods to make this work:

```
def parser(identifier: String, default: String): String = genParser[String](identifier, default, identity)
```

Is there a reason I can't overload when type parameters are in use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overloading is not what the compiler is concerned about.

```
<console>:8: error: method parser: (identifier: String, default: String) String does not take type parameters.
```

This code:

```
parser[String](identifier, default, identity)
```

calls this method:

```
def parser(identifier: String, default: String): String
```

instead of this one as you would want:

```
def parser[T](identifier: String, default: T, modifier: String => T): T
```

This illustration compiles just fine:

```
val args = Array[String]()

def parser[T](identifier: String, default: T, modifier: String => T): T = {
  val l = args.filter(_.startsWith(identifier))
  if(l.isEmpty) default
  else modifier(l(0).drop(identifier.length).trim)
}

def parser(identifier: String, default: String): String = "dummy"
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Do you have any idea how I could specify which "parser" I am using when defining the method?

Comment: Not really. Consider a slightly other design, where you would have a `transformer` of type `String => String` instead of the `modifier`, which is of type `String => T`. Knowing, that you need a function `String => String` you can provide a default value of the identity function like `s => s`) instead of overloading the whole method. You can modify the results in the next step.